# How do I apply XsltSettings AND XmlReaderSettings in loading a transformation?

Tags: asp.net, xml, asp.net-2.0, xslt

I'm trying to load a xslt transformation in .NET 2.0 .  I'm taking in an XML Document already in memory, as it's dynamically generated before hand.  When I use the XMLReader option with ProhibitDTD=false , I get an error saying that I need to enable scripts in the XsltSettings.  If I use the Load method with XsltSettings (Trusted), I get the DTD error.  Any thoughts on how to apply both ProhibitDTD=false AND EnableScript=true ?

```
    public static string ConvertXML(XmlDocument InputXMLDocument, string XSLTFilePath, XsltArgumentList XSLTArgs)
{
    StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    XslCompiledTransform xslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.ProhibitDtd = false;

    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(XSLTFilePath, settings);

    try
    {

        //xslTrans.Load(reader);
        xslTrans.Load(XSLTFilePath, XsltSettings.TrustedXslt, new XmlUrlResolver());

        xslTrans.Transform(InputXMLDocument.CreateNavigator(), XSLTArgs, sw);

        return sw.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it - there was an overloaded method that didn't seem too obvious with the proper types, but it works.

```
public static string ConvertXML(XmlDocument InputXMLDocument, string XSLTFilePath, XsltArgumentList XSLTArgs)
{

    StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    XslCompiledTransform xslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.ProhibitDtd = false;

    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(XSLTFilePath, settings);


    try
    {

        xslTrans.Load(reader, XsltSettings.TrustedXslt, new XmlUrlResolver());
 //       xslTrans.Load(XSLTFilePath, XsltSettings.TrustedXslt, new XmlUrlResolver());

        xslTrans.Transform(InputXMLDocument.CreateNavigator(), XSLTArgs, sw);

        return sw.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Error email code omitted

    }
    return "";


}
```